# Finding one expected value by using another expected value.

Tags: statistics

Hi I am trying find the following problem

A nonnegative random variable $X$ is defined as $Z = \log(X)$ where $E(Z) = 0$ and $V(Z) = \sigma^2 > 0$. Is $E(X)$ greater than, equal to or less than $1$?

First thing it is not given that $Z$ follows normal distribution so I think it is not valid to take that $Z$ follows normal distribution. Using the definition of expected value I couldn't get anywhere. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Because $\log(\cdot)$ is a concave function, we can apply Jensen's inequality (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)) to say that $$\log(E[X]) \geq E[\log(X)] = E[Z] = 0 \Longrightarrow \log(E[X]) \geq 0 \Longrightarrow E[X] \geq 1 $$

As pointed out by [Ian](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83396/ian), we can further say that these inequalities holds strictly because $\log(\cdot)$ is a strictly-concave function, and therefore we can conclude that $E[X] > 1$.

Comment: log is concave, not convex.

Comment: Whoops, thanks.  Noticed something iffy as soon as I pressed submit.

Comment: Note that since log is strictly concave and X is nonconstant, the inequality is strict.